# How to reliably overwrite existing database using Powershell Restore-SqlDatabase cmdlet

Tags: sql, powershell, sql-server-2012

I got this cmdlet to restore a database and it works fine if there is nothing using the existing database.

```
Restore-SqlDatabase -ServerInstance $databaseServerInstance -Database $database -BackupFile $backupLocation -ReplaceDatabase
```

But overwrite fails when the database is in use with:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError: Exclusive access could not be obtained
>   because the database is in use

I couldn't figure out if there is an easy way (via an argument) to override this and kill connections or put the database in single user mode.  is there such a thing?  or do I have to switch to SMO to do anything more complicated than a basic restore?

I am now using a workaround of using SMO API to drop the DB first but would love to simplify this if its possible.

```
$srv = new-object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server($databaseServerInstance)

# If the database exists then drop it otherwise Restore-SqlDatabase may fail if connections are open to it
if ($srv.Databases[$database] -ne $null)
{
    $srv.KillAllProcesses($database)
    $srv.KillDatabase($database)
}


Restore-SqlDatabase -ServerInstance $databaseServerInstance -Database $database -BackupFile $backupLocation -ReplaceDatabase
```

Comment: Thanks for the handy PS :) Helped!

Answer (score 8):

I'm using Invoke-SqlCmd for it. [Invoke-SqlCmd](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc281720.aspx) is part of sqlps module, which you can download from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42295):

```
Push-Location; 
Import-Module sqlps -DisableNameChecking; 
Pop-Location

$serverPath = "SQLSERVER:\SQL\localhost\Default"
$databaseName = "YOUR_DATABASE"
$restoreFrom = join-path (Get-Location) "$databaseName-before.bak"

$databasePath = join-path $serverPath "Databases\$databaseName"
if(Test-Path $databasePath)
{
    Invoke-SqlCmd "USE [master]; ALTER DATABASE [$databaseName] SET  SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE; DROP DATABASE [$databaseName]"
}

Restore-SqlDatabase -Path $serverPath -Database $databaseName -BackupFile $restoreFrom
```

You can find more information on how to use Invoke-SqlCmd here:

[Effectively Using Invoke-SqlCmd](http://www.mikefal.net/2015/03/31/effectively-using-invoke-sqlcmd/)

[SQL SERVER – FIX – The term ‘Invoke-Sqlcmd’ is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2014/11/23/sql-server-fix-the-term-invoke-sqlcmd-is-not-recognized-as-the-name-of-a-cmdlet/)

Answer (score 0):

There is no argument in Restore-SqlDatabase to kill all processes that uses the database you want to restore.

You can execute the script below for a full documentation of arguments in Restore-SqlDatabase

```
get-help Restore-SqlDatabase -full
```

Answer (score 0):

Years later I ran into the same problem, but wanted to stay in the SMO. The solution was to use the `TerminationClause Enum` documented on the MS page [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.terminationclause?view=sql-smo-160).
The termination enum is used in line:

```
$db.alter(1)
```

and utilises either:

```
0 --> (default) FailOnOpenTransactions
1 --> RollbackTransactionsImmediately
```

Full solution would look like this:

```
$Instance = 'localhost'
$dbName = 'DB_I_Want_To_Restore'

$server = New-Object ('Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server') ($Instance)
$db = $server.Databases | ? {$_.Name -eq $dbName}

$db.useraccess = 'Single'
$server.KillAllProcesses($db)
$db.alter(1)                                      

Restore-SqlDatabase -ServerInstance $Instance -Database $dbName -BackupFile 'location_of_your_backup_file'
```

Answer (score -1):

Set the database into [single user mode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522682.aspx) and roll back any existing transactions. This is done with a Tsql statement like so,

```
ALTER DATABASE MyDatabase SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
```

As you are already on it, why not get rid of the database before doing the restore?

```
USE master; -- or some other db than the one you are going to drop
DROP DATABASE MyDatabase;
```

Another an approach is to [restore the database](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186858.aspx) with using the `WITH REPLACE` option.

Comment: I was looking for a Powershell solution involving no SQL scripts.  I already have one that works but it needs dropping of DB - see in my question above.  But I thought just the "Restore-SqlDatabase" cmdlet will work with some flags I don't about.